# Insert data to Dynamics crm in Foreach Loop

Tags: ssis, microsoft-dynamics, kingswaysoft

I want to insert data to Dynamics CRM inside the Foreach loop.
For Example:

First get campaigns based on condition.
Then for every campaign get contactlist from another DB and create marketing list with these members. Is it possible with SSIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a common use of Kingwaysoft's Dynamics CRM tasks.

The short version of this is you'll write SSIS tasks to authenticate your connection to CRM, write a for loop, use a OLE DB source task to enter data using [Kingswaysoft's CRM Destination](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365/help-manual/crm/destination) task and loop based on criteria you provide.

The "campaign on condition" aspect of your hypothetical package is likely something you'll need to filter in your OLE DB Source Task.